# D'où vient l'appellation « Fonction Objectif » au détriment de « Fonction Objective » ?

Tags: accord, informatique, mathématiques

Le terme fonction objectif est très couramment utilisé en Optimisation Mathématique et dans d'autres domaines comme l'informatique. En anglais, il se traduit par "objective function". Tandis que fonction est féminin, pourquoi n'accorde-t-on pas objectif, ce qui donnerait « fonction objective » ?

Quelles sont les origines de cet accord ?

https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fonction_objectif

Answer (score 9, accepted):

C'est parce que l'adjectif [**objectif**](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/objectif) n'équivaut pas au substantif [**objectif**](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/objectif/2) utilisé ici.

Le rôle de cette fonction est d'atteindre **un** objectif optimal, un but déterminé, où objectif est masculin alors que « *fonction objective* » serait compris comme une fonction qui s'appuierait sur des critères objectifs, qui font référence à une réalité tangible, le contraire de « *fonction subjective* », fonction qui s'appuierait sur une opinion ou un raisonnement personnel invérifiable.

La confusion vient du fait qu'en anglais l'adjectif *objective* et le substantif *objective* s'écrivent de la même façon.

Une hypothétique « fonction soustraction » (donc qui soustrait quelque chose), traduirait l'anglais *subtract function*  alors que « fonction soustraite » (*subtracted function*) serait un contresens.

Comment: "l'adjectif objectif" ? Dans "*la fonction objectif*", *objectif* est un nom, non ? C'est d'ailleurs LA raison pour laquelle il ne s'accorde pas.

Comment: @TeleportingGoat Oui, c'est bien ce que je veux dire. Il existe un adjectif nommé *objectif* qui s'accorde, mais ce n'est pas ce qui est utilisé ici. L'article ***un*** est là pour indiquer que c'est bien du nom commun qu'il s'agit.