# Les fonctions objectifs / objectives / objectif ?

Tags: accord, pluriel

Suite à [cette précédente question](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/33720/do%C3%B9-vient-lappellation-fonction-objectif-au-d%C3%A9triment-de-fonction-object), je me pose la question de l'accord de fonction avec objectif au pluriel.

Dit-on que nous minimisons les fonctions :

- objectifs ?
- objectives ?
- objectif ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ce qui est sûr, c'est que ce ne seront pas des *fonctions objectives* !

Si on considère que la fonction est un objectif, qu'il y a équivalence entre les deux termes, il n'y a pas de raison de ne pas accorder le nom :

> Les fonctions **objectifs**.

Si ce n'est pas le cas, pas d'accord :

> Les fonctions **objectif**.

L'usage semble fluctuer...

Comment: Merci ! C'est néanmoins contradictoire avec la réponse de LPH...

Comment: Pour une fois, il n'a pas complètement tort. Les deux se rencontrent. La règle étant qu'il y a accord s'il y a relation d'équivalence entre le nom apposé et le nom principal. Si la fonction est un objectif: accord, si elle ne l'est pas: pas d'accord. Je te laisse choisir ;-)

Comment: Oui, j'ai précisé « lorsque nous minimisons...» voulant spécifier le contexte :) +1 pour vous deux

Answer (score 2):

On doit laisser le substantif inchangé mais utiliser le [pluriel](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/fonction_objectif) pour le mot « fonction » ;

- des/les fonctions objectif

Les fonctions objectif sont conçues relativement à un objectif, chacune relativement à un seul objectif et non plusieurs. On pourrait très bien considérer des fonctions qui chacune sont conçues relativement à plusieurs objectifs et alors le nom composé au singulier serait écrit « fonction objectifs » ; au pluriel on dirait « une fonction objectifs » et « des fonctions objectifs ».

Pour renforcer cela, en se basant sur le principe dans ce [commentaire](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/37979/les-fonctions-objectifs-objectives-objectif/37982?noredirect=1#comment76154_37981) il n'y a pas d'équivalence (ce ne sont pas des fonctions qui sont elles-mêmes des objectifs mais elles permettent d'atteindre un objectif), ce qui indique qu'il ne faut pas d's.

Comment: Merci ! C'est néanmoins contradictoire avec la réponse de jiliagre...

Comment: @JKHA C'est le Wiktionnaire qui a raison ; je crois comprendre le principe régisseur de cet usage moi-même, mais difficilement ; j'essayerai de fournir une explication.

Comment: Sur ce lien _http://tanopah.jo.free.fr/ADS/bloc14/vtsracinenieme.pdf_, on emploie le terme _les fonctions racines_. De même, on parle de fonctions exponentielles et le "s" s'accorde. On dit "le logarithme" mais "les fonctions logarithmes". Sur ce point, j'ai envie de rejoindre @jiliagre et mettre un _s_ à objectif.

Comment: @Kenichi-san Je crois que d'abord il ne faut pas mêler le cas de l'adjectif modificateur et celui du substantif modificateur; si on considère  « exponentielle » comme un adjectif il n'y a pas de question, c'est la norme pour tous les adjectifs. Pour les cas « racine » et « logarithme » il me semble que l'on peut justement s'appuyer sur le principe que user jlliagre met en avant en se posant cette question (pour logarithme) : est-ce que la fonction logarithme est une fonction qui est aussi un logarithme ou est-ce une fonction qui est associé à un logarithme ? (champ 1/5)

Comment: @Kenichi-san Selon les définitions actuelles dans « log x = a » on appelle à la fois « log » le logarithme et  « a » le « log de  x » ; il faut donc savoir comment on a défini sémantiquement « fonction logarithme »; est-ce que « logarithme » signifie la fonction ou est-ce que cela signifie le nombre que la fonction produit ? Je ne crois pas que l'on sache cela ; tout ce que le TLFi mentionne c'est que « logarithme » signifie le nombre produit ; selon ce point de vue unique il ne faut pas de s, c'est la fonction qui sert à produire un logarithme. (champ 2/5)

Comment: @Kenichi-san Il y a aussi le point de vue suivant : « si *a* est un réel positif (strict) et différent de 1, la fonction 'x → a puissance x' est un isomorphisme du groupe additif des réels dans le groupe multiplicatif des réels positifs (strict). Son isomorphisme réciproque qui, à tout réel *y>0* associe *x* tel que *y=a puissance x* est appelé logarithme de base *a* et noté *log sub a*. ». Il n'y a pas de doute que la fonction, selon ce point de vue, est un logarithme. (champ3/5)

Comment: @Kenichi-san Toujours selon ce point de vue on utilisera un s selon comment on défini le composé « fonction logarithme » ; comme c'est souvent le cas pour ce genre de question cela a été fait au petit bonheur la chance : il n'y a pas moyen de savoir si l'on entend par cela « qui produit un logarithme » (s) ou si on entend « qui est un logarithme » (équivalence, et donc pas d's). Il n'en est pas de même pour objectif : on sait clairement que la fonction n'est pas elle-même l'objectif mais que c'est le nombre qu'elle produit par maximisation ou minimisation qui est l'objectif. (champ 4/5)

Comment: @Kenichi-san Pour le cas « exponentielle » où ce mot est considéré comme étant un substantif (reconnu dans le TLFi) le  problème ne se pose plus parce que l'on n'appelle exponentielle que la fonction et on fait cela par ellipse ; on ne peut donc pas considérer que dans « fonction exponentielle », « exponentielle » soit le substantif, ce ne peut être que l'adjectif et il faut toujours s au pluriel.(5/5)

Comment: Merci pour l'explication :)